# 指定した色の構造物を、U-Netで抽出したい

Tags: python, 深層学習

色、形状などを基に、セマンティックセグメンテーションを行いたいです。現在はU-Netを使うつもりです。ただし、色の区別をマルチクラスセグメンテーションを使ってしたくないので、その方法を教えていただきたいです。

例えば、黄色、赤色、青色のコインのピクセルを抽出したいときに、黄色のコインのアノテーションだけを使って形態やテクスチャを学習させ、あとから色閾値を入力することで赤や青にも対応できるようにしたいです。

今持ってるデータだけではこの先使いうる全ての色を網羅できていないのと、色数が多く、いちいちラベルしていられないからです。

RGBを入れ替えたり、値を補正するなど、前処理を工夫することでそれなりにはできたのですが、データサイズがかなり大きいため、そのような処理もできるだけしたくないと思っています。もっとシンプルな方法はないでしょうか・

他の戦略や似たような例を教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。